# how to select specific data based on id

Tags: sql, database

Table of data

```
id  |  regiondId     |     provId    |    munId   |     brgyId   |   deleted
1   |      4         |       41      |     411    |     411001   |      1
2   |      4         |       41      |     411    |     411002   |      1
3   |      4         |       41      |     412    |     412001   |      0
4   |      4         |       41      |     412    |     412002   |      0 
5   |      4         |       41      |     413    |     413001   |      0
6   |      4         |       41      |     413    |     413002   |      0
7   |      4         |       41      |     414    |     414001   |      0
8   |      4         |       41      |     414    |     414002   |      1
```

sample I wanted to select 413 in `munId`, but before I can select 413 I need to select region and prov first.

This is my query would look like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbldata 
WHERE regionId = '4' 
    AND provId = '41' 
    AND munId = '413' 
    AND brgyId = '' 
    AND deleted != 1
```

So 1 is deleted and 0 is not deleted
but using AND operator returns null since my brgyId = null and if i replaced AND operator and use OR near brgyId it fetches all data with munId 413 even if it is deleted .

is there a way to get the specific data based on the given value like if I

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbldata where regiondId = '4' 
    AND provId = '41' 
    AND munId = '413' 
    AND brgyId ='413001' 
    AND deleted = 1
```

I get the data with id 5 and if I

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbldata 
WHERE regiondId = '4' 
    AND provId = '41' 
    AND munId = '413' 
    AND brgyId = '' 
    AND deleted = 1
```

i get the data with id 5 and 6
and if i

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbldata 
WHERE regiondId = '4' 
    AND provId = '41' 
    AND munId = '' 
    AND brgyId = ''
    AND deleted = 1
```

i get the data with id 1 to 8

Comment: What database are you using ? Can you update your question and add an expected output ?

Comment: As it is, your question is not easy to understand... Instead of pseudo-SQL code, would you please try to explain your requirement by showing expected output(s) ?

Comment: what i wanted to do is  if either one or two of the values is null it should still return some data if it exist on my table. but the keys are required .. just like my example as you can see from region to brgyId it is still included in my query even if the value is null or not. im using mysql as my db.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care of the values in a certain column, just don't include any restriction on it in the `WHERE` clause.

For example to get the rows with `id`s `5` and `6`:

```
SELECT *
       FROM tbldata
       WHERE regiondId = '4'
             AND provId = '41'
             AND munId = '413'
             AND deleted = 0;
```

Note, that there is no operation on `brgyId` in the `WHERE` clause.

(If the datatype of the columns is actually a numerical one, you can also remove the single quotes.)

Comment: what i want is to include the brgyId also not removing it. so whether if the value of each column id is null or not it should be included.